# Strange bug when running fortran subroutines in python

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I've compiled some of my fortran subroutines with f2py so I can run them in python.  At first they seemed to be running fine but then I encountered a bug that takes place under circumstances that shouldn't have an affect.

Basically I have a fortran subroutine that has an inout variable called deaths.  It continually adds to deaths when I run it in a python loop.  It was producing the correct death numbers until I added a print statement to the python loop that output a variable which didn't have anything to do with the subroutine.

I tried printing the deaths variable directly from the fortran code and the deaths variable was increasing in large random steps when it was supposed to increment by one.  This bug was also triggered when I added completely unrelated code elsewhere to the python file.

One thing that may be relevant is that I create the deaths variable with a fortran subroutine as a one valued array because that's the only way Ive been able to make variables that can be modified by a fortran subroutine.

Any suggestions on how to go about debugging this?  I tried compiling with the --debug-capi flag.  I compile the python code with Ubuntu's Geany.  Is there a better way to wrap fortran subroutines?

My compilation:
f2py   -c -m fann FANN.f

or

f2py --debug-capi  -c -m fann FANN.f

```
#Here are some code samples:

import fann

deaths = fann.make_integers(1)

#below code produces the correct deaths value
for i in range(steps):
  fann.walk(W,signs,3,M,N,Dm,deaths,bohr) 



#below code produces the wrong deaths value
for i in range(steps):
  fann.walk(W,signs,3,M,N,Dm,deaths,bohr) 
  if(1%20): print Rf
```

! I was asked to show the fortran code:

```
    SUBROUTINE walk(W,sgn,potentialType,M,N,Dm,deaths,bohr)
    IMPLICIT NONE
          INTEGER, PARAMETER :: sizeGr = 20000
      INTEGER :: potentialType
      INTEGER :: i , j , k , l , d , q, M, N, Dm
          INTEGER, INTENT(INOUT) :: deaths
      REAL*4 :: dx1(N,Dm), W(M,N,Dm), bohr
      REAL*4, SAVE :: rand, green(sizeGr)
      LOGICAL, SAVE :: first_iter = .TRUE. 
      LOGICAL :: deleted(M), sgn(M)

Cf2py intent(in) N
Cf2py intent(in) Dm
Cf2py intent(in) M
Cf2py intent(inout) sgn(M)
Cf2py intent(inout) W
Cf2py intent(inout) deaths
Cf2py depend(M,N,Dm) W
Cf2py depend(M) sgn
Cf2py intent(in) potentialType
Cf2py intent(in) bohr


        IF(first_iter) THEN
          CALL tabulate_green()
          first_iter = .FALSE.
              deleted = .FALSE.
        END IF 

        ! iterate over walkers
        DO i = 1, M   

          ! stochastically move walker to new possition with a gaussian probability
          DO k = 1, N
            DO d = 1, Dm

              CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand)
              W(i,k,d) = W(i,k,d) + green( INT( rand * sizeGr ) + 1 )

            END DO
          END DO

          CALL potential(i)

        END DO 

        DO i = 1, M   
          IF( deleted(i) ) CALL death(i)
        END DO

            deleted = .FALSE.

      CONTAINS

        SUBROUTINE tabulate_green()
          IMPLICIT NONE
          INTEGER :: p , n , sizeGr2 = sizeGr/2
          REAL*8 :: x , xol , Sy , dx , pi , halfGreen(sizeGr/2)

                  dx = 1.0/10000000
                  pi = 4.d0*atan(1.d0) 
          n = 0
          x = 0.0
          Sy = 0.0
          DO p=1,100000000
            Sy = Sy + dx*SQRT(1/(pi*2))*EXP(-(x**2/2))
            x = x + dx
            IF(Sy.GT.(n/(2.d0*sizeGr2))) THEN
              halfGreen(n) = (x + xol - dx)/2
              xol = x
              n = n + 1      
            END IF   
            IF(n.GT.sizeGr2) EXIT
          END DO

          DO n=1,SIZE(green)
            IF(n.LE.sizeGr2) THEN
             green(n) = -halfGreen( sizeGr2 - n + 1 )
            ELSE
              green(n) = halfGreen( n - sizeGr2 )
            END IF
          END DO

          END



        SUBROUTINE potential(itt)
          IMPLICIT NONE
              INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: itt
          INTEGER :: s, l
          REAL*4 :: v, work
          REAL*4, SAVE :: const
              LOGICAL, SAVE :: first_itt = .TRUE.

            SELECT CASE (potentialType)

            CASE(1)


            CASE(2)


            CASE(3)

                  IF(first_itt) THEN
                const = 1/(2*bohr**4)
                first_itt = .FALSE.
              END IF 


              v = 1/(2*bohr**4)*SUM( W(itt,:,:)**2 )
              CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand)
              IF (rand.GT.EXP(-v)) THEN

                    CALL death(itt)

                  END IF


            END SELECT

          END



        SUBROUTINE death(itt)
          IMPLICIT NONE
              INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: itt
          INTEGER :: jt 
          REAL :: rand2

            CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand2)
            jt = INT(rand2*M) + 1

                DO WHILE( jt .EQ. itt )
              CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand2)
              jt = INT(rand2*M) + 1
                END DO

            W(itt,:,:) = W(jt,:,:)
            sgn(itt) = sgn(jt)

          END 


    END
```

Comment: What do you expect us to do without seeing the Fortran code?

Comment: It might also help if we had some idea what all those parameters were...

Comment: Well I can't really follow what you are doing, but I can say that the array deleted is being use uninitialized on the second and subsequent calls.

Comment: Too much code is missing. I'll suggest a course of action: create all the argument arrays (that need to come in and out) with numpy with Fortran ordering and declare them inout in the fortran code. I have done that already for some codes with success. Ex: `deaths = np.array([1, 2, 3], order='F')`. For scalar values this is not needed.

Comment: How do you create a numpy array with demensions specified by integers?